# Redirect from Web Api to MVC controller if Identity Role is not Admin

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

How to redirect from web api controller to mvc home controller when use is not Admin.

```
// GET api/adminleave
        public IEnumerable<ObjectModel> GetPendingLeave()
        {
            if (!User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            {
                var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Moved);
                response.Headers.Location = new Uri("example.com");
                return response;
            }
        List<ObjectModel> obj=new List<ObjectModel>();
       return obj;

        }
```

I am tried as above but got error.

> Error 27  Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a
>   cast?)    F:\WebPortal\WebApplication1\Controllers\Leave\AdminLeaveController.cs  34  24  WebApplication

**how can i redirect form hom webapi controller when i am returning Object list from webAPI controller**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do, doesn't make any sense in terms of MVC/WebAPI relation. In MVC a whole website is served by your server, using WebAPI you rely on client-API relation, in which you create an API, which can be consumed by whoever you allow to.

You can't mix those approaches in terms of redirection. What you can do is to inform your client, that a redirect is needed in this specific scenario(but this still is not an ideal solution) and perform a redirect on the client side.

Just think about it - if you create an API, which can be consumed by "everyone", does it seems a right thing to do to perform such redirects? Another option would be to call an action in your MVC controller and get the results, but I assume you would like to go to the another page when an user has an "Admin" role.